# Creating a filtered search based on different parameters

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i need to create a filtered search based on different paramnters chosen by a user. So, for example, my app is a property app. I want them to be able to define the county, town, max,min bedrooms ect from a dropdown list and press search, and this returns all the properties that match the criteria.

How do I go about doing this? I can't find any tutorials online, but maybe I'm not phrasing it right.

Here is an image of what I'm after from a UI point of view.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCG3X.jpg

Comment: Have you ever worked with Laravel in the past or this is your first attemt?

Comment: I have about 2 months experience with laravel. Currently self taught. I'm trying to learn as much as possible. I have always wanted to create a search filter like this, but I don't know where to start

Comment: Self promoting ahead: https://github.com/Kyslik/laravel-filterable go through the code and see how its somewhat done; also here is a [link (for paid) laracasts video](https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-techniques/episodes/4) where I got idea from

Answer (score 1):

The following is an easy to go solution considering your experience.

- Create a new controller or a method in an existing one.
- First create a simple form (method GET) in blade that will return predefined values from simple hidden fields
- Create a new GET route in which the form must be submitted and link it to the controller method that you created
- In your controller method get the submitted form data from your request, make the correct queries and return the blade template file that contains the form with the results
- Modify blade template to show results
- Finally replace the hidden fields with selects drop-downs and modify your controller in order to populate them

You can make the form submission process and the select drop-down fields population asynchronous but based on your experience with Laravel it should be hard. Following the steps above will do your job.

> Always take a look to the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests). You will ge a lot of help from there.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go, and report back

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this for filter options in your controller

```
public function filter(Request $request, Property $property)
{
  $property = $property->newQuery(); 

  // Search for a property based on country
  if ($request->has('country')) {
    return $property->where('country', $request->input('country'));
  }

  // Search for a property based on their area.
  if ($request->has('areas')) {
    return $property->where('areas', $request->input('areas'));
  }

 // Search for a property based on max_price
  if ($request->has('max_price')) {
    return $property->where('price','<=', $request->input('max_price'));
  }

  // Continue for all of the filters.


  return $property->get();
}
```

For more info refer the [link](https://m.dotdev.co/writing-advanced-eloquent-search-query-filters-de8b6c2598db)

Comment: Thanks. I found that tutorial previously. But there was no section to set up models, migrations or even the UI